# How can I graph the time evolution of an initial state under a given hamiltonian in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, simulation

I'm trying to compare the graphs of the time evolution of a state under the action of a given hamiltonian (Heisenberg, Ising). I have the graphs of the classical simulation using the ~ and @ functionality in Qiskit. The problem is I do not know how to graph the time evolution when I run a trotterized circuit on real backend (say manila). I calculated the fidelity when the simulation runs for time $t = \pi$ but that's about it. Thanks in advanced to anyone who provides help.

Comment: Could you please share a source code you have written so far? It can help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `Statevector` class from `qiskit.quantum_info` can help you. It contains many attributes, such as `Statevector.inner()`, which allows to calculate inner products and much more. You may try to convert the state you get after the simulation using your backend to this class. Something like this:

```
from qiskit import BasicAer, transpile
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

# Function that returns the state vector of a circuit as Statevector class with the BasicAer statevector_simulator

backend = BasicAer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")

def Simulate_statevector(q_circuit):
    tqc = transpile(q_circuit, backend)
    job = backend.run(tqc)
    result = job.result()
    psi_qc = result.get_statevector(tqc, 4)
    return Statevector(psi_qc)

# Example

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)

Psi = Simulate_statevector(qc)

# Checking the probability density

Psi.inner(Psi)
```

In my [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqkyCsvQYy8nuO86yD3IBHQ) I've made some tutorials on this topic. Maybe you can find them useful. To know more about `qiskit.quantum_info` you can also check the [Qiskit documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/quantum_info.html) and the [Qiskit pocket guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/qiskit-pocket-guide/9781098112462/), which are in my opinion very concise and useful references.